# Reactjs child component goes into infinite loop on setting state array provided by parent in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent element fetches array from server and provides child element in props to show array (tickets).

## Parent Element

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={outerBoundary}>
                <ShowArray tickets={this.state.tickets}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

## Child Element

```
 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    var tablePadding = {
      'padding':'1em',
    }
    this.setState({
      tickets:this.props.tickets,
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className={classes.root} style={tablePadding}>
          <Typography variant="title" id="tableTitle">
            Array Elements
          </Typography>
          {this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.length > 0 && this.state.tickets.map((n, index) => {
            console.log(n, index)
            return (
                <TableRow> n.id </TableRow>
            );
          })}
     )
 }
```

Problem that i am facing is ticket state that i am setting in child element using value of props goes into infinite loop.

```
this.setState({
  tickets:this.props.tickets,
});
```

[image: Error message displayed]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Why you are using setState in render()  function

Comment: I used this.props.tickets.map directly for array in jsx but this was also going into infinite loop. I did not get the error but my console was filled infinite log inside loop

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `setState` inside your `render` function

```
this.setState({
  tickets:this.props.tickets,
});
```

as the `setState` function is causing a re-render so on the next render you will call `setState` again and you will need to re-render again so that's why you have the loop

Comment: I replaced 

this.setState({
      tickets:this.props.tickets,
    })

with
console.log(this.props

and used this.props.tickets.map directly in the array. Now I am not getting any error but console.log() prints infinitely. Why is my render function getting called again and again

Comment: Please share your full code, and your new error so we could address it

Answer (score 1):

Don't setState in render. You can map props instead:

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    var tablePadding = {
      'padding':'1em',
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Paper className={classes.root} style={tablePadding}>
          <Typography variant="title" id="tableTitle">
            Array Elements
          </Typography>
          {this.props.tickets.map((n, index) => {
            console.log(n, index)
            return (
                <TableRow> n.id </TableRow>
            );
          })}
     )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this.setState from the child's render method and try the below in your child component,

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   if(nextProps.tickets){
      return {
         tickets: tickets
      }
   }
}
```

Inside the render of child component,

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { tickets } = this.state;
    var tablePadding = {
      'padding':'1em',
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Try this...

Comment: I replaced this.setState({ tickets:this.props.tickets, }) with console.log(this.props and used this.props.tickets.map directly in the array. Now I am not getting any error but console.log() prints infinitely. Why is my render function getting called again and again

Comment: Are you sure, there is no setState in both parent and child component's render method ?

Comment: Try pasting the code which I have given above, to your child component and tell me whether it works

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what everyone else has said, you are using `setState` in the `render` method.

It appears you are changing the `state` using the `props`

```
this.setState({
  tickets:this.props.tickets,
});
```

In your code, you do not need to do this, you can use `this.props.` directly instead of `this.state.tickets` in `jsx`.

However, should you need to update your state based on the props, you should use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

With that, you can write a `static` method like this

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return {
        tickets: props.tickets
    }
}
```

The return value of `getDerivedStateFromProps` is used to update the state. In this case, the `tickets` key in `state` will be updated with the value of `props.tickets`.

Comment: I replaced this.setState({ tickets:this.props.tickets, }) with console.log(this.props and used this.props.tickets.map directly in the array. Now I am not getting any error but console.log() prints infinitely. Why is my render function getting called again and again

Comment: The `render` function is called whenever `react` has detected a change in the shadow dom. Birds eye view of how react works is, it keep a copy of the [dom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) in memory. When you make a change, say you however over a ticket to display more information, it first changes the shadow dom to match what you want ( a dom containing a div over a certain ticket ) and compares it to the real dom. It then changes the real dom to match the shadow dom. This is done by calling `render`. Your render function is called because the dom changes.

Comment: As a few debug tips, first see if you encounter the same issue if you just leave the app alone ( depending on implementation, even scrolling can trigger a re render ) If the problem continues, you need to see what triggers the re render. Usually, this is triggered by a change in props or state. Look for calls to setState to find state changes and look in the parent to see prop changes. It could be the case that `tickets` is being given over and over again. Also, now I noticed, you should add [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to TableRow.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the infinite loop, call `useEffect` and pass in `[this.props.tickets]` as the second argument.

The lambda in the first argument will then only be called when `this.props.tickets` changes value, limiting the number of times the state will be updated.